# Equivalence of a set of norms depending continuously on a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, normed-spaces, compactness, finsler-geometry

Background: In the paper "Lusternik-Schnirelman Theory on Banach Manifolds" by Richard Palais, the author defines a Finsler structure (Definition 2.1) in a general way, where roughly speaking, given a topological space $\mathcal{B}$ and a vector space $V$, one assigns a norm $\|\cdot\|_b$ on the space $V$ at each point $b \in \mathcal{B}$, subject to the following  continuity condition. At each $b$, and for any $K>1$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $b$ such that the equivalence 
$$\frac{1}{K}\|\cdot\|_{b_0} \leq \|\cdot\|_b \leq K\|\cdot\|_{b_0} $$
holds for all $b_0 \in U$.  I am wondering if in the finite dimensional case, this property holds true as soon as we assume that the map $(x,u) \mapsto \|u\|_x$ is continuous for the product topology on $\mathcal{B} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Formally, Let $\mathcal{B}$ be $\mathbb{R}^k$ and let $\|\cdot\|_{b}$ be an assignment of a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to each point of $\mathcal{B}$, in such a way that the map $(b,u) \mapsto \|u\|_{b}$ is a continuous function from $\mathcal{B} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then for any $K>1$ is it always possible to find a neighbrohood $U$ of $b$ for which there is a constant $K$ such that
$\frac{1}{K}\|u\|_a \leq \|u\|_{b_0} \leq K\|u\|_b$ for all $(b,u) \in U \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Thanks!

Comment: The notation suffers from using "B" in many ways: as the norm identifier, as the parameter, and as the topological space $\mathcal{B}$.  Also I would make it clear one way or the other that $\mathcal{B}$ is assumed finite dimentional throughout.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it to say that $\mathcal{B}$ is finite dimensional. The norm is determined by the parameter B, thats why I put in the subscript. I'm open to a better notation if you can suggest one.

Comment: I don't have a better idea for notation; sometimes the reuse of a symbol is felicitous.  However I'd feel better about it here if there were more of a motivation for identifying (constructing?) a norm depending on "point" $B\in \mathcal{B}$

Comment: Dear @hardmath I have refined the question and added more background.

Comment: Thanks.  I think your approach works, taking the infimum over the compact set to get a lower bound just as the supremum gives an upper bound.